# Why can't my Titanium build app find a module even though it's clearly there?

Tags: javascript, module, titanium, directory-structure, titanium-modules

I'm trying to use the sculejs module that I downloaded with GitHub. It seems like the com.scule.js-file should be placed in the same folder as app.js, according to the provided example. But the most recent versions of Titanium (I think) don't use that structure.

Here is what I add to the index.js-file located under app/controllers:

```
var scule  = require('com.scule.min');
```

This results in the emulator giving me "Application Error Couldn't find module: com.scule.min."

Here is what my app's folder system looks like:
[image: folders]

Anyone know what's wrong? Or maybe can push me in the right direction to get it to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There should only be controllers in the controllers directory. So you should remove all but index.js.

Next, create a lib directory and put your commonjs libraries there. Also, remove com.scule.min.js from the app directory.

It's important to use the correct [directory structure](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Concepts-section-34636240_AlloyConcepts-ConventionoverConfiguration) in Alloy. Otherwise, your files will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
var scule  = require('/controllers/com.scule.min');
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little late for your needs - but I thought I'll just put an answer here anyway for others to see.

It seems you are using "Alloy" with Titanium - that is good! I am relatively new to Titanium but I am quite sure Alloy is the way to build apps in Titanium.

Within Alloy you need to put all your CommonJS libraries in a "lib" folder which is at the same level as controllers, views and styles. Create the folder if it does not already exist.

Once you have put your com.scule.js (which I use) - or com.scule.min.js in the "lib" folder then you can easily include it in the other modules (e.g. your controller or another of your own libraries in the lib folder). Just write:

```
var scule = require('com.scule') // Basically, the file name without the last ".js"
```

I don't know if your problem could be related to 'com.scule.min.js'? I haven't tried that - but I use 'com.scule.js' in my current app ;-)

/John